# Can we accept such words as 'invite' when used as a noun in correct English?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

So often people tell me they have had an 'invite' to something, I am wondering if the word can actually be accepted as correct English, as opposed to 'invitation'. In a similar vein people, more usually in the north of England, will use the present participle of verbs in situations which call for the past. E.g. Waiter in restaurant asks you 'how would you like your eggs cooking?'instead of 'cooked'. Are these not simply incorrect expressions in English? It just seems to me that nowadays if enough people start saying something it becomes acceptable.

Comment: Every single word in your post is incorrect English if you go sufficiently far back. Every single one. An invite is not English? Well guess what, an invitation is not English either, it's French. And what, pray tell, are "restaurant", "participle", "opposed", "verb", "acceptable", "correct", "actually" supposed to mean? You make no sense at all. Please rewrite your question in English. Thank you.

Comment: On a more serious note, you will have to rewrite your question anyway, as in its current form it's peeving disguised as a question (off-topic here), a loaded question with a false premise (again, off-topic), mixing two unrelated things ("an invite" is in a similar vein as "your eggs cooking"? sorry, not similar *at all*), and subjective and argumentative to boot. (What do you mean, "can we accept"? "We" don't get to decide anything. As the answers show, the words *are* accepted, and have been for centuries, sitting right there in the dictionary.) Please edit to address these concerns. Thanks.

Comment: Pray what is the difference in changing the English language by using 'invite'as a noun, and changing it by using a present participle where the past is needed? Both, in my view are examples of bad English in everyday use. One may happen to be used more in America, (though I hear it a lot in Britain) and the other more common in Yorkshire. I am getting the view that you and some of your colleagues are rather nervous about discussing certain things.

Comment: WS2, you hit the nail on the head when you wrote *that nowadays if enough people start saying something it becomes acceptable.* That seems to be the reason why people misuse the word *invite*, in that way. A lot of people are like sheep, just blindly following others.

Comment: WS2. The answer to the question in your title is: Is 'invite' listed as a noun in standard dictionaries? If so, then you can use it as such.

Comment: WS2 As regards your comment "I am getting the view that you and some of your colleagues are rather nervous about discussing certain things." As I've pointed out to you in another of your questions, this site is primarily a Q&A site, not a *discussion* site - please refer to the first two sections under *Asking* on the [Help page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help). Your primary Q is off-topic because it can be answered by a dictionary. Your expanded Q & comment are OT because they are "primarily opinion-based". (Please note, I didn't write the rules - I'm merely quoting them!)

Comment: @WS2, your personal preferences and peeves do not dictate what is and is not ‘correct’ English. ‘Correct’ does not mean what you think it means when discussing what is and is not acceptable language usage. ‘An invite’ might not be correct (= grammatically and idiomatically acceptable) in _your_ English, but it is perfectly acceptable, if informal, in more or less everyone else’s English. In _my_ English, the last sentence in your question is ungrammatical. It is also factually incorrect: this is not a ‘nowadays’ phenomenon—it is how _every_ language has _always_ evolved and been defined.

Comment: "It just seems to me that nowadays if enough people start saying something it becomes acceptable." --- YES. this is how language works.

Comment: @sgroves So what is the role of bodies who set examinations in English grammar? Indeed what is the purpose of studying English grammar?

Comment: @ws2 i was simply commenting on the asker's apparent ignorance of the fact that languages continually change over time. it should not be surprising that some use *invite* instead of *invitation* or that this is becoming more popular.

Comment: @sgroves A lot of odd ways of saying things are 'becoming more popular' simply because the standards of literacy are falling.

Comment: @ws2 people have been expressing that lament for hundreds of years. sounds like you're just the latest.

Comment: @sgroves Obvious, y'know innit!

Answer (score 5):

Of course we can. *Invite* has been used informally as a noun since at least 1659, when it occurred in Hamon L'Estrange’s 'The alliance of divine offices exhibiting all the liturgies of the Church of England':

> Bishop Cranmer . . . gives him an earnest invite to England.

Comment: Now that is a good answer which I can accept. But I wouldn't mind betting that if I was lucky enough to receive an invitation to the Buckinham Palace Garden Party or to something on the lawn of the White House, the card would not be headed 'INVITE'.

Comment: It would not. An invitation from Buckingham Palace begins with ‘The Lord Chamberlain is commanded by Her Majesty to invite . . .’ As I said, _invite_ is informal, but then so is much of the rest of the language we use every day.

Comment: But in that instance 'invite' is used perfectly correctly as a verb. I bet when you went to the Palace you never heard anyone use it as a noun! I mean Alan Sugar might have, but I bet none of the officials did!

Comment: Sorry, should have called him Lord Sugar!

Comment: I know. I quoted it not because I thought _invite_ was being used as a noun, but because I thought you might be interested in the wording used.

Comment: Yes I was. I have never had one.

Answer (score 2):

[I don't think there is anything wrong with using *invite* to mean *invitation*.](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/invite)

> **invite** <sub>noun, informal</sub>
>
> an invitation.

Note: the pronunciation for the noun form is /ˈɪnvʌɪt/ instead of /ɪnˈvʌɪt/.

Comment: Well I do. I think it is hideous!

Comment: @WS2 Then don't use it.

Comment: @WS2 and I think "hideous" is hideous. It is not an English word. Why don't you just say "ugly" instead?

Comment: @RegDwight. It is in the OED.

Comment: @WS2, so is ‘invite’ (noun).

Comment: This is getting silly. Let's move on people.