# Is 'overreach' just a verb?

Tags: verbs, nouns, parts-of-speech, nominalizations

Reading an [article](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/12/27/opinion/dont-trash-colombias-democracy.html?ref=colombia) on the *New York Times* website, I came across the verb 'overreach' functioning as a noun. I immediately looked it up on the net and apparently it's just a verb, so I wanted to know what's going on here: is it a translation issue or does it have to do with some dialectical/sociolinguistic/idiolectical affair (which I doubt, because the text is supposedly standard American, right?)? Thanks.

Comment: Just about any English verb can be used as a noun in one way or another; sometimes several ways. Ditto nouns used as verbs. "Noun" and Verb are labels for uses for words in sentences, not labels for properties of the words themselves.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, but to what extend can a word belong to another part of speech? I mean, dictionaries generally register the phenomena, but what if they don't - like in this case in point? Is it just plain language change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we accept such words as 'invite' when used as a noun in to correct English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131292/can-we-accept-such-words-as-invite-when-used-as-a-noun-in-to-correct-english)

Comment: Words do not **belong to** a POS. Rather, parts of speech describe how words are used. Period. Labelling a word as a verb or a noun does not imprint a character that can't be changed. You might as well label all humans as good people or bad people, based on one piece of experience.

Comment: There seem to be a couple of thousand noun usages in Google Books for ["an overreach of"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an+overreach+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). It doesn't even strike me as "unusual".

Comment: @John: Not wishing to be accused of "generalising", I think I might be on reasonably safe ground saying that all leaders of North Korea called "Kim" are *bad despotic tyrants.* Of course, the *next* one might turn out to be "one of the good guys".

Comment: @John Lawler: I feel you misinterpreted me, because we’re on the same page here. I don’t mean to use POS as a prescriptive way to understand language, but rather as a means to explain linguistic phenomena. Actually, I can’t agree more with you. I have checked the Corpus of Contemporary American English and the word ‘overreach’ is tagged as noun too. But in instances like these my question would be: how come dictionaries and lexicographers do not always report such trends? (That's why I was thinking it was probably language change.)

Comment: No, whether it's a noun or a verb or an adjective or a complementizer or a determiner ... is a matter of use, in thousands of construction types in billions of sentences, daily. Dictionaries don't do that. Dictionaries are to word usage as the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy's listing for Earth is to all the knowledge of the human race. So dictionaries don't go near that, except in frozen form as idioms. This is grammar and usage, not word lists.

Comment: Dictionaries report upon the usage that major editors allow past their noses. Even the venerable OED does not create content. It reports on its usage in other publications.  Once something reaches whatever critical mass is necessary, the usage become a dictionary case.

Answer (score 1):

Overreach can be a noun. It's not a common one, but it can function as one.

> Thanks to governmental overreach, the citizens were wary of any new initiative no matter the good intentions behind it.

I believe it is a noun in that sentence. Again, it may be a mildly awkward noun, but still a noun.

Comment: But by the same reckoning, very is a noun in 'Thanks to governmental very, the citizens were wary of any new initiative no matter the good intentions behind it.' OP is asking what level of acceptability / frequency of use, and by whom, **licenses** the usage. Dictionaries are still a very useful way of checking on acceptability (which most check by frequency studies). OED is usually taken as the chief arbiter. And Inquisitor uses the terms 'noun' and 'verb' in acceptable and generally understood ways. He's essentially asking 'Who decides whether X can be used as a noun as well as the verb?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your example is correct. Very would be used as a noun in that case. But, as it's not used in that way by anyone authoritative it loses validity. Overreach by comparison has been appropriated as a verb turned noun by multiple publications, etc. Given that my answer preceded the extensive commentary I stand by it.  As to who gets to decide, I would say that's what editors of major publications are paid to do. The OED merely reports on their usage.

Comment: Often on contentious issues such as this, publications have in-house style guides (for word usage as well as grammar). And again, they often disagree from company to company. I don't accept that as an acceptable definition of 'getting to decide'. I'll go with OED (and companies B, C, F & J and organisation Q) rather than companies A, D... and organisations P and T ... until OED revises.

Comment: Well, they are the ones who allow it to reach the public. Assuming the public does not reject their edits as unreadable (*i.e.* ceasing their readership), then the same editors continue to allow similar content to reach the public. Once this usage reaches critical mass, the OED, *et al* take notice and make it a dictionary case.  So, if you object to the word decide, I'll allow you to strike it. But, the underlying premise is the same.

Comment: Many people sing '...this world in which we live in.' I don't.